# CKEditor: pass value back to link-plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

To insert a link to specific files I want to add a button to the link-Dialog, which opens my own php-filebrowser.

In this filebrowser I can browse specific directories to finally select a pdf-file.

By clicking on a file I want to pass the url of this file to the link-dialogs url-field. And that is the point where I do not get ahead.

The url I alert when clicking the file is the one I need.
All I need is the javascript to pass it to the opener's url-field.
I have tried several proposed solutions I found in this forum but nothing helped.

In my filebrowser I have a list of files.
Each file has a link like this one:

```
<a href="javascript:passvalue('*my_file_with_path*');">*filename*</a>
```

This is the javascript part I tried in my filebrowser:

```
<script>
     function passvalue(url) {
       alert (url);
       opener.SetValue(url, 'url');
       window.close();
     }
</script>
```

The script alerts the correct value. But the next line doesn't pass the value back.

Instead of "opener.SetValue(url, 'url');" I also tried
`window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(ckeditorfuncnum, url);`
with the ckeditorfuncnum passed to the script and
`opener.SetUrl(url);`

UPDATE:
it seems as if the second try ('window.opener.CKEditor...') would be the right one. Since no value is displayed in my input field, I tried to return an error message...
The error message is being displayed in the window with the CKEditor-Fields.

Comment: you will need to post the code of the solutions you have tried. Stackoverflow is not meant to give you free code.

Comment: I have tried several options I found in this forum:
(url contains the value to pass back)
- "opener.SetUrl(url);"  
- "opener.SetValue(url, 'url');"  
- "window.opener.CKEditor.tool.callFunction(funcnum, url);"  (funcum contains the value submitted to the script)

Comment: update your original post and add as many code as you can which is relevant for your question. it is nearly impossible to answer your question with the information you have given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who might run into the same problem here is the solution:

```
function passvalue(url) {
    var dialog = window.opener.CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
    dialog.setValueOf('info', 'url', url);
    dialog.setValueOf('info', 'protocol', 'http://');
    window.close();
  }
```